# My left navigation, does not work the same in Firefox, and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox

I have a left navigation menu
`<ul><li>` style with background images,
my menu is not within an iframe,
but when i click a menu element in firefox , new page comes like i never leaved that page,
feels like kinda Ajax used in the page,
But when i click the link in the menu in IE7, i can recognize the page refresh, i can see that i leave the page and 
can i achieve same result in IE,

Comment: A bit of code?  This is not nearly enough information for any hope of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i'm correct FF does not refresh the viewport if you are about to visit a new page, only when the page is loaded (there are some delay thresholds), IE does. without ajax or any other desynchronized / selective loading thing you cant achieve the same effect.